# What's the difference between Jackdaw and KillerBee on RZ Raven USB Stick

Tags: security, iot, zigbee

What is the difference between Jackdaw and KillerBee on ZigBee USB Stick, both seem to be sniffing packet, but Jackdaw can act as a network interface, and KillerBee is only used for pentest? As far as I understand it, you can't use either to connect to like a hub or Wireless router, but only to ZigBee based devices, which would be the IoT devices such as sensors or smart socket etc.

Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.